# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Append to a cloned search not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the [jQueryUI Autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget on my search form, It's working great on my initial search box, the user has the option to add another row using an add button, this fires a function that clones the master search:

```
$("#search_input").clone(true).addClass("cloned_terms_" + add_count).attr("id", "search_input_" + search_input).appendTo("#clone");
```

this adds identifiers to the row, then i'm adding a data-id attribute to the new search box:

```
$(".cloned_terms_" + add_count + " input").val('').removeClass("search_input_0").addClass("search_input_" + search_input).attr("data-id", search_input);
```

However when I try and use the [appendTo](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option on the autocomplete, it doesnt show, If i view the page in the console the list is there but doesnt show, I've tried adding the `ui-front` class to various parts of the page with no luck, any help would be appreciated, here is the function to create the autocomplete:

```
function setAutocomplete ( source , autocomplete_selector )
{

    console.log("autocomplete_selector: " + autocomplete_selector);

    $(autocomplete_selector).autocomplete({

        source: source,

        autoFocus: true,

        minLength: 1,

        disabled: false

    }).focus(function() { // refocus the autocomplete if the user clicks away from a partially complete search

        $(this).autocomplete("search");

    });

}
```

This is called initially on the first search input, and works great:
[image]

however when I add another search row. I either get the autocomplete attached to the initial search or it will not show, Any help? Cheers

**EDIT**
Here I'm at the point where I'm getting the desired effect, but it is only visible in the console, the user can't see the options?
[image]

Comment: Can you use inspect element to make sure data-id attribute is added to the new search box?

Comment: yes, data-id is added and working, tjhe initial search has data-id of 0 and each added rows searchbox has the correct data-id, eg: 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: where are you using the appendTo option?

Comment: Ive tried it in different ways, in the setAutocomplete function:
appendTo: autocomplete_selecter

Ive also tried setting it like so:
$(autocomplete_selecter).autocomplete("option", "appendTo", autocomplete_selecter

Comment: Sorry for not being much of a help but I am out of answers. Would recommend you to debug step by step. Add add results manually from the console to see if it works.

Comment: the help is apreciated, Ive got to a stage where its working in the console but the ul is "invisible" to the user, I think its something to do with the z-index